# Application hotkeys don't work in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

Two Systems (dual boot): but both use the same /home partition and show the same problem:

- Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - recent LTS release.
- Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS with kde desktop.

In "Edit Applications", several shortcut keys are set. For example Meta+W for Brave Browser:
[image]

In `.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` there is section with corresponding key

```
[brave-browser.desktop]
_k_friendly_name=Brave Web Browser
_launch=Meta+W,none,Launch Brave Web Browser
```

In the list of global shortcuts it's also present
[image]

But `Meta-W` do nothing.

Standard debug step returns empty line

```
$kreadconfig5 --file .config/kglobalshortcutsrc --group brave-browser.desktop --key _launch
```

Comment: Please provide an OS & release details.  You mention two OSes, one on-topic & the other off-topic, but no release details. Please mention a specific OS & release.

Comment: @guiverc I've update the question. I think versions are irrelevant, because PoP_OS uses kubuntu repositories for KDE, it seems (not sure). The problem in KDE and I wonder, how to check it and whether there is more comprehensive way to debug the problem.

Comment: Kubuntu doesn't have repositories; all *flavors* of Ubuntu use Ubuntu repositories, otherwise they'd not be a Ubuntu *flavor*.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories  Kubuntu being a *community* supported product uses `universe`.